# mysql speed problems

Tags: mysql

Any advice on how i can get this query to run faster?

```
SELECT *, p.*
FROM grouped g 
INNER JOIN form p 
on p.id = g.id 

LEFT JOIN prospect ps 
ON (p.appphone = phone_bus OR p.appphone = phone_res OR p.appphone = phone_fax) AND p.appphone != '' 
WHERE p.agname like '%test%'
ORDER BY p.agname DESC 
limit 0, 100
```

If i change the ON to not use OR it runs quickly. Like this it takes 30-40 seconds.

p.appphone, phone_bus, phone_res, phone_fax, and p.agname are all indexed in table.

Comment: How many rows are in the tables you're querying?

Comment: @brian 80,000 in p , 60,000 in ps and 80,000 in g

Comment: Thanks. Where is this db hosted?

Comment: Are your columns indexed separately or in one / two indexes? If not separately what are they?

Comment: could you post `CREATE TABLE` statements and an `EXPLAIN` for your query, please?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an inner join, that should go fast if indexed properly, the left join on the match '%test%' is probably where it is taking the time.

it is going through your max 60k rows, (you are selecting all columns), and when it gets to the field agname, it has to traverse the string to match the word test somewhere in the string 60,000 times. I would say optimize the '%test%', if there's noway around this... you could

appphone - how many different scenarios are there --

```
ON (**p.appphone = phone_bus OR p.appphone = phone_res OR p.appphone = phone_fax**) AND p.appphone != ''
```

you could join on the key, and then use your nested OR statement in the WHERE clause, no?

Maybe you could say where p.appphone <> phone_print or something that will include this nested OR statement, but optimizes it so it just looks for what it's not instead of three different instances of what it could be....also does p.appphone really = '' or is it null? Not sure exactly how much faster it will make it but you could say where p.appphone is not null on the left join as mentioned earlier.

Comment: if i take out the OR in the ON statement it runs quickly. i need to search on all those cases in the ON.

Comment: Then unfortunately, I think it will take awhile, unless you create a table to house the results of the inner join and then left join on that, otherwise it is a lot of work for mySQL backend. Have you tried only indexing on agname and appphone?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to:

1. Use `ANY` operator;
2. moving `p.appphonne != ''` into the `WHERE` clause;
3. precise `SELECT` list, 'cos `*` already includes the `p.*` fields.

Please, try this query:

```sql
SELECT *, p.*
  FROM grouped g 
  JOIN form p ON p.id = g.id 
  LEFT JOIN prospect ps
    ON p.appphone = ANY(ps.phone_bus, ps.phone_res, ps.phone_fax) 
 WHERE p.agname LIKE '%test%'
   AND p.appphone != ''
 ORDER BY p.agname DESC 
 LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Please, include `EXPLAIN` output of the query in your first message.